# How to set JScrollPane in JFxPanel instead of default scroll bar to handle ScrollBar related events

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to open HTML file in JavaFX WebView using JFxPanel .By Default JFxPanel is creating its own scrollbar  .I want to handle the events with the scrolling of JFxPanel . So can i set JScrollPane in JFxPanel to set the customize position of the scroll bar or how could i catch the events associated with the scrollbar in JFxPanel.

In fact I want to get the current position of the scroll bar in JFxPanel and also set
  the  page according  to previous scrolling position.

Comment: Don't know much about JFxPanel, but if it has a model, perhaps you can set it as the model of the JScrollbar (or make a class that wraps the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html of a JScrollBar)

Comment: I want to handel JScrollbar of JFxPanel by java code, For example JFxPanel scrollbar set on particular position